# video isn't playing uicollectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have feed in which different categories have multiple videos fro this I use UICollectionView with in UIStackView. when I scroll to uicollectionview it take some time to load video and their is lagging when scroll

code to play video in UICollectionview cell

```
      self.videoPreview.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
                      if $0 is AVPlayerLayer {
                          $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
                      }
                   }
                
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.templateURL)
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                playerLayer.frame = self.videoPreview.bounds
                self.player!.isMuted = true
                self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                self.player!.play()
                self.layoutSubviews()
                self.videoPreview.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image]